# How to display full screen images on remote system?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Local system running Python application.

Remote system, Ubuntu Desktop.

Goal:  Have remote system display full screen images sent by local system.  Think digital signage or digital photo frame.

Current approach:

FTP image to a directory on the remote, then issue the following via SSH:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
feh --fullscreen --hide-pointer <local image file>
```

Problem:

Switching to a new image requires killing feh and re-issuing the command.  This has the effect of showing the Ubuntu desktop for a quick fraction of a second before the new image appears.

Is there an approach that would simply allow the local system to send a new image to the remote and have it seamlessly show this new image?

At the moment I'm thinking I might need to install a Python program on the remote that monitors a given directory for changes and manages image display directly.

Comment: What about killing the first feh **after** you launch the second?

Comment: have you tried to pass appropriate options to `feh`? (so that a single `feh` process would handle the slide show for you)—you could pass it directories, urls too

Comment: This isn't for a slide show.  I need to send new images at undetermined intervals and have them displayed. A slideshow would be easy but that's not what I need.